# Doctrine @id null when persisted

Tags: symfony, doctrine

The following works and a row in inserted into both tables:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setId(8484);
$user->setData("user test data");

$profile = new Profile();
$profile->setBlah(8484);
$profile->setData("profile test data");

// if I leave this out it works... 
$user->setProfile($profile);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();     

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

But if leave out `$user->setProfile($profile);` I get an error because `User`'s id is null:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO User (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)' with params {"1":null,"2":"user test data"}
```

How can it be?

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $data;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="blah")
     */
    protected $profile;
}

class Profile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="blah", type="integer")
     */
    protected $blah;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $data;
}
```

Set Profile method:

```
/**
 * Set Profile
 *
 * @param \Test\AdminBundle\Entity\Profile $profile
 * @return User
 */
public function setProfile(\Test\AdminBundle\Entity\Profile $profile = null)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;

    return $this;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If I change the joinColumn name to something random my object looks right using a var_dump but the query fails:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="random_test", referencedColumnName="blah")
 */
```

Gives:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO User (id, data, random_test) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":8484,"2":"user test data","3":null}:
```

Comment: How does your `setProfile()` look like?

Comment: Don't you need to add $em->persist($profile); too, before your flush?

Comment: @Anonymous: no, because I will only save a `User` object.

Comment: @user1070125 - How can that user object reference your profile object if it's not stored anywhere though?

Comment: I have the same opinion like Anonymous. You should flush() new Profile first!

Comment: User does not need to have a profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your $profile persisted before Doctrine can successfully make a relationship between your user and your profile.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();    

$user = new User();
$user->setId(8484);
$user->setData("user test data");

$profile = new Profile();
$profile->setBlah(8484);
$profile->setData("profile test data");
$em->persist($profile);

$user->setProfile($profile); 
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Think about what you are trying to do in your code in MySQL.

Originally you were saying:

*Insert a user who's profile will be (8484)*

Which results in *(Err: Profile 8484 doesn't exist).*

What you want to say is:

*Insert a profile (8484).
Insert a user who's profile is (8484).*

Comment: No, because a user do not need a profile. I can susccesfully fetch user and optinally a profile object using a left join. Now I need to save user with a optinal profile object.

Comment: Wrong, you user does need a profile. Your relationship is one to one. You need to change the type of relationship if you want a profile to be optional, or create a default empty profile which is always in the db (id = 0?). That's bad practice though.

Comment: What kind of relation would that be? One user belongs to one profile. That's why I thought it's one to one. My example may not be the best but think of a profile (object) with a optional profile photo (object)

Comment: You have the right idea, but if a relation is one to one, both sides must exist. The relation you have is 0 or 1 to 1. There's some info here on why this doesn't work in Doctrine: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/3nnVWwr4Ch0 . Unfortunately there isn't a great way to do this. I would recommend one to one, where you have some logic that can tell if a profile is empty or not. That way every user will always have a profile, even if it's not filled out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link. It explained my problem very well.